# How to change Font.Bold of an array content with C# in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

With Excel VBA I can write/set array of range for example Range("A1:B2, C2:D3").Font.Bold = True, so it will make A1, A2, B1, B2, C2, C3, D2 and D3 Font->Bold.

But then I try this with C# i get "Exception from HRESULT:0x800A03EC", and I can't figure why?

I know range has some limits but considering speed and other stuff its best way to set Font.Bold as range at once rather make separate calls on each cell.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Is it working separately? I mean `Range("A1:B2").Font.Bold = True` and `Range("C2:D3").Font.Bold = True` ?

Comment: have you selected the active sheet before calling the range function? like so `Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B2, C2:D3")`

Comment: Show your code! - In C# one usually  has to assign a new code object not just change a property of an existing one.

Comment: @Teamothy yes It's working then I use it seperately.

Comment: @styx yes it's on active sheet[also 1 sheet only in workbook]. But code written in c# not VBA.

Comment: @styx _with.Range["A1:B2, C2:D3].Font.Bold = True
_with -> Excel.Application.

If i write: _with.Range["A1:B2].Font.Bold = True it's working. If I add C2:D3 then not. If i write it on Excel VBA -> working both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A range can be part of Range() parameters. Please give a try to below style -

```
Excel.Range range1 = _with.Range("A1:B2");
Excel.Range range2 = _with.Range("C2:D3");

_with.Range(range1,range2).Font.Bold = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some speculation here, short of seeing your actual C#, but I believe this code will work:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet;
sheet.Range["A1:B2,C2:D3"].Font.Bold = true;
```

So my only guess is that you used parentheses () instead of brackets [].

In VBA, function parameters and indexers both use parentheses.  In C#, function parameters use parentheses, but to invoke an indexer you need to use the square brackets.

Does the code above give the same error?

Comment: Sadly I get same error number Exception from HRESULT:0x800A03EC.

Seems @Ritesh Kulkarni solution is the only one.
Excel.Range range1 = _with.Range["A1:B2"];
Excel.Range range2 = _with.Range["C2:D3"];

_with.Range[range1,range2].Font.Bold = true;

Comment: Very interesting...  I'm glad you found a solution, but I have to ask -- are you using Interop or some third party tools?  I'm curious why this works fine for me and throws an error for you.

Comment: I'm using Excel VSTO-Add-In with Visual Studio 2010 and Office 2007. 
Declarations:
Using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application _with = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

Comment: Forgot to mention, my code a bit different: Excel._WorkSheet shh= ((Excel._Worksheet)_with.ActiveSheet); and then shh.range[.....]